# apple.SE account not showing up in network profile

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation, user-accounts

Why isn't my apple account shown among my [accounts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6825/fudo?tab=accounts), nor in my [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/37373bc9-16dd-4393-87f1-899f4d458c2e?tab=accounts)?

I suspect this is the reason why I did not get a +100 rep bonus from my (>200 rep) [math](http://math.stackexchange.com) account, here…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleared your associations and reassociated your accounts. This seems to have fixed the problem, as well as given you your 100 rep bonus.

Comment: many thanks for your swift solution!

Comment: can't upvote though: somehow my meta.apple account wasn't affected by the change :(

Comment: @fudo Sometimes it takes a little while for reputation changes to a primary account to show up in the meta account. However, it appears that you're now at 111 rep here as well.

Comment: yeah, I guess I was being too impatient :)